# Prediction of linear RGB color in Vertex Paint

Tags: python, image, vertex-paint

I'm using VertexPaint to generate masks for specific vertex groups on meshes together with AOV and rendering to EXR.
It's very important for me to be able to control the exact color values that's rendered.
I understand that the input values that's set using Vertex Paint are set using SRGB then transformed to linear space.
But it seems to me the transformation isn't perfect and the colors I get are actually not the exact colors I'm setting.
Can any one point me to the correct solution for this?
I understand that the transformation user by blender is lossy, but is there a way to be able to predict what exactly will the values be transferred to?

I have tried few suggestions: playing with color management, setting display device to srgb or none:

[image]

This is the Compositor setup:
[image]

The result always the same for all setups, input = (0.2, 0.3, 0.4) - sRGB
Output:
[image]

The color is wrong - Blueish color on the side of the cube.

Comment: For exact reproduction and use as a mask, your best bet is to UV map and bake vcol to a non-color image texture, then use that instead of vcol.

Answer (score 1):

Change render properties -> view transform -> to "Standard"

[image]

Comment: Standard still does a color transform, just a different one than Filmic.  Display device to none would do it, but unfortunately comes with side effects that Shay Gusin will probably find undesirable...

Comment: Well...I will let decide Shay whether he is happy with that or not.

Comment: From all my tests with color management.
None of the options change the output.
It seems to me some black magic is going on in AOV.